# AJAX Defaults Config

Tags: ajax, jmeter

Can someone please give me an explanation of AJAX Defaults Config or what is the role of it in Jmeter?

I tried to search for an answer in Google but I can't find a definite definition of it.

Answer (score 1):

As of [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) there is no such a thing as  `AJAX Defaults Config` in [JMeter Components](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) so most probably you're using some form of [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is not publicly available. If this is the case you should reach out to the plugin developers/maintainers for the clarification.

For the vanilla JMeter, as per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Therefore JMeter is not capable of automatically execute [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests because `J` letter stands for [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)

If you need to properly simulate AJAX requests you need to add a separate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler per AJAX call and put them under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) to ensure